# Determine when a checkbox is unticked and clear a field

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to detect when a checkbox is un-checked and if the corresponding field below (with an Id) has a value, then empty it.

Any ideas?

I'm working with the following but it isn't working:

```
$('#end_date_specified').click(function() {
 $('#end_date_datepicker, #end_date_datepicker_altfield').empty();
 $('#datediv').toggle();
});
```

I think one of the problems with this is that it will empty the field values no matter how the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Uncheck? Could we see your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
$('#end_date_specified').change(function() {
  if(!this.checked) {
    $('#end_date_datepicker, #end_date_datepicker_altfield').val('');
  }
  $('#datediv').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Only on `change` (better than `clicked` to get the right state) we only clear if it's not [`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Input), then we show the `#datediv` based on whether it's checked (show if it is, hide if it isn't) using [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: The `change` event is only fired when the input element loses focus (and the new value/state differs from the old one). Usually, when you click a checkbox, the element retains focus until you click somewhere else on the page. Using the `click` event instead of `change` event is more user-intuitive for checkboxes and radiobuttons.

Comment: @BalusC - jQuery normalizes the `change` event to behave as expected here, and `click` is bad to use because you'll get the *previous* state in many cases.  Try it yourself: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/C64P5/

Comment: Oh, jQuery normalizes it? Never knew that. Is that specified somewhere? By the way, how so getting the previous state in many cases? If a checkbox is clicked, its state is changed anyway.

Comment: @BalusC - yup, in the `.change()` docs: http://api.jquery.com/change/ "For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus."

Comment: Great, I just realised though that it needs to be .val('');

Comment: Thanks, Nick :) Nice job by jQuery.

Comment: @user275074 - Updated the above to be more accurate.  @BalusC - in cases of bubbling, or cancelling the event, I can't think of an example off hand atm, since some of this was fixed in jQuery 1.4.2+, but it's come up dozens of times in SO questions (the entire reason they were having issues).

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are going to be clearing that div no matter what, as you say.  What you want to do is check for the "checked" attribute on your check box.  If it is false/undefined/null then do the empty.

```
$('#end_date_specified').click(function() {
 if(!$('#end_date_specified').attr('checked')) {
     $('#end_date_datepicker, #end_date_datepicker_altfield').empty();
     $('#datediv').toggle();
 }
});
```